# Replacing second part of string with Javascript and replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace any occurrence of a sequence of integers followed by a dash and then another sequence of integers, with only the first sequence of integers. For example:

```
THIS IS A STRING   2387263-1111  STRING CONTINUES
```

Will become:

```
THIS IS A STRING   2387263  STRING CONTINUES
```

Can I use that with Javascript and `replace()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
str = str.replace(/(\d+)-\d+/,'$1');
```

[**See it**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/PEBMc/1/)

Which replaces a group of digits followed by a hyphen followed by a group of digits with the first group of digits.

If you want to replace multiple occurrences of such pattern just use the `g` modifier as:

```
str = str.replace(/(\d+)-\d+/g,'$1');
```

Comment: This would remove the string after "-" only for first occurrence right? eg:- if string is "This 12-43 23423-342 string" then ouput would be "This 12 23423-342 string". Hopefully OP does not have this use-case.

Comment: Actually in my case I only need it for the first occurrence :) @Sachin - thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Sachin: You are right, only the first occurrence would be affected. OP can use `g` modifier to affect all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

NEW ANSWER -

Yes, in your case according to me, first you need to match that whole string "2387263-1111" using a regex and then remove that part followed by '-' and then replace the result in the original string.

Check the answer from **codaddict**. Mine would've almost been same but his answer seems more appropriate.

OLD ANSWER: -

Why replace? Just use split and get the first value.

```
var str = "2387263-1111";
var output = str.split("-")[0];
```

Comment: Because this is a substring, it is not the whole string. I need to look up that part

Comment: @gidi - In any case you will get hold of that substring and then parse to get the first value before "-" right?.If not, then can you give your exact use-case and update your question?

Comment: sorry I was not clear enough. I edited the question with the string I have, the exact use-case. The problem is that I do not know how to get a hold of the desired substring.

Comment: @gidi - yeah, now it makes sense. Thanks. I will try to get proper answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

User [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) function of javascript

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp("-[0-9]+"), " ");
```

Comment: This will fail if the input is `foo -1`

Comment: @codaddict - It won't fail, unless there are digits after - and that is what gidi wants.

Comment: Requirement is clear: `sequence of integers followed by a dash and then another sequence of integers`

Answer (score 1):

Not really a new answer, just an addition to **codaddict**. Don't know JScript's regex
all that well, but I asume it uses extended regular expressions (if not, forget this).

If you need validation on boundry conditions you could do something like this:
`str = str.replace( /((^|\s)\d+)-\d+(?=\s|$)/g, '$1' );`

That would prevent matching this type of thing:
`A STRING 2387263-1111STRING CONTINUES`
`A STRING2387263-1111 STRING CONTINUES`
`A STRING2387263-1111STRING CONTINUES`